# Find an algorithm that sorts the nodes of a given graph acc. to distance from source node + value of the node's key

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

an unweighted connected graph $G=(V,E)$ all nodes of the graph contain a "serial number" between 1 to V. (V is an integer).

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that sorts all nodes firstly by distance (number of eadges) from source node 's' , secondly- if two nodes have same distance value sort them by value of thier serial number.

complexity required is $O (V+E)$

I tried to solve this via using bfs and then recieve a "bucket" array of distances - for each distance $1,2...$ all nodes within it are in its "bucket".
the problem is, that in order to sort two nodes with same distance according to
their serial number takes at least $O( nlogn)$ of sorting.
 I tried to come up with a use $v-1$ empty arrays and tried to send each "bucket" nodes acc. to their index in the graph and print it - that takes )$V^2$.

This is NOT homework, I really did try my best.
Your comments are appreciated.

Comment: Complexity of sorting serial numbers is O(N), not O(N log N): you can use radix sort or counting sort.

Comment: When you are sorting all nodes with distance $i$, assume that you are sorting a separate array using linear sort. Basically, you want to perform the linear sort two times.

Comment: @user118972 What non-homework use of this do you have that requires the exact complexity of O(V+E)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. Use BFS to calculate the distances.
2. Calculate the scores (sums of distance to source and serial number).
3. Use [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) to sort the scores.
4. Go over the list again and output the vertices in sorted order.

Comment: Hi!  Could you please elaborate more on this approach?  If i  am not mistaken, this would fail for the following graph  :  (s,a),(s,b),(b,c) where   sn(a)=4, sn(b)=sn(c)=1.   score(a)=5  whereas score(c)=3 so     final answer would be [b,c,a] instead of [b,a,c]

Comment: @jjohn You need to create a vector `d[serialNumber] = distance from source to node associated with serialNumber`; then you can use counting sort on it.